# Async function not returning firebase object in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a react app that retrieves a JSON object from Firebase in componentWillMount. I've set up an async function to make the call to Firebase, however it doesn't return with the object, and instead the callback function itself. I'm a bit confused on promises and need some clarification..

Here's my getMessages async function

```
import loadDB from './db';

// create a promise that returns snapshot.val
export default async (keyProp) => {
  try {
    const db = await loadDB()
    const key = db.ref('hashtags/' + keyProp)

    const response = await key.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.val(); //Firebase Object displays in console.log here
    })

    return response
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('fetch failed', err);
    return null
  }
}
```

And here is my componentWillMount

```
import getMessages from '../lib/get-messages.js'

componentWillMount() {
        const key = this.props.url.query.name

        getMessages(key)
          .then(function(messages){

            // messages displays function (snapshot) {snapshot.val()}
            // in console.log instead of my firebase object 
            console.log('msgs', messages)
          })
      }
```

I think the issue has to do with `const response` and it not returning the firebase object..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have to `return` value from the below function :

```
const response = await key.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   // snapshot.val(); --> this need to be returned
   return snapshot.val();
})
```

Comment: Added it. Still getting the same response though.